# character encodings used by FileWriter, DataOutputStream, OutputStreamWriter and RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, encoding, stream

`FileWriter`, `DataOutputStream`, `OutputStreamWriter` and `RandomAccessFile` can write character data to underlying streams or files, can anybody summarize what are the default character encodings they are using, can they be set to use other encodings than the default ones?

Comment: Neither `DataOutputStream` nor `RandomAccessFule` uses a charset at all, and the others use the system default charset. This is all clearly stated in the Javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

- FileWriter: uses the default encoding
- DataOutputStream: doesn't write characters. Writes bytes. So encoding is irrelevant. Except for `writeUTF()`, which uses modified UTF8 encoding (read the documentation for more details)
- OutputStreamWriter: uses the encoding passed as argument to the constructor
- RandomAccessFile: doesn't write characters. Writes bytes. So encoding is irrelevant. Except for `writeUTF()`, which uses modified UTF8 encoding (read the documentation for more details)

All this is available by just reading the javadoc.

Comment: `OutputStreamWriter` has a constructor where you don't need to specify encoding so it resorts to default charset.

Answer (score -1):

For `OutputStreamWriter`, if the charset is not specified, it will get the default charset from `Charset.defaultCharset().name();` (which, if not identified will resort to using `UTF-8`). This is assuming that you are running an Oracle Java JDK where the class calls the `StreamEncoder.forOutputStreamWriter` which is a sun package.

`DataOutputStream` writes bytes so no encoding is needed.

`RandomAccessFile` reads and writes bytes so no encoding is needed.

`FileWriter` is a subclass of `OutputStreamWriter` so it'll use the default encoding used by `OutputStreamWriter`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The default charset is not `UTF-8.` [The default charset is determined during virtual-machine startup and typically depends upon the locale and charset of the underlying operating system.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset())

Comment: I don't dispute that @EJP. If the default charset is not determined in that aspect, it will resort to using `UTF-8`. I am looking at the code right now.

Comment: You don't dispute it but you didn't state it either. You can't argue with what it says in the Javadoc, whatever might be in the code.

Comment: I specified both, since the code does what it does and I can't dispute with code.